# using the same connection postgresql across multiple source files in C

Tags: c, postgresql, tcl

I'm trying to create a single connection between all my source files to the postgres db this is how i'm trying to share the conn, I'm new to this postgres api so still learning.

Main C program:

tp_main.c:

```
// system header
#include <tcl.h>
#include <tk.h>
#include <blt.h>
#include </usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h>
#include "dbConn.h"

PGconn *conn;

int Tcl_AppInit(Tcl_Interp *interp) { 
    char sTclFile[] = "./maingui.tcl";

    if (Tcl_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR) return TCL_ERROR;
    if (Tk_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR) return TCL_ERROR;
    if (Blt_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR) return TCL_ERROR;
    if (Tcl_EvalFile(interp, sTclFile) == TCL_ERROR) return TCL_ERROR;

    Tk_MainLoop();

    Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
    Tcl_Exit(0); 
return TCL_OK;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) { 

   //Initiate database connection
   conn = PQconnectdb("dbname=jw1_v2 host=localhost user=imdw password=1234");

   if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
       printf("Connection_Error\n");

   }else{
     printf("Connection_Ok\n");
   }

     Tk_Main(argc, argv, Tcl_AppInit);
return 0;
}
```

I'm using a header file to try and make the 'conn' variable a global variable this is the header file:

```
#include </usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h>

#ifndef DBCONN_H
#define DBCONN_H

extern PGconn *conn;

#endif
```

This is one of the source files that try to use the connection, but I get undefined symbol conn:

Samples.C:

```
#include <tcl.h>
#include <tk.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include </usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <blt.h>
#include "dbConn.h"

extern PGconn *conn;
PGresult *res;


 static int sampleList(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[]){
    Tcl_Obj *result;

    if (objc != 1) {
            Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "number of argument error");
           return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    char command[256];
        PQclear(res);

    strcpy(command, "SELECT \"allSamplesDates\"()");
    res = PQexec(conn,command);

    result = Tcl_GetObjResult(interp);
    Tcl_SetStringObj(result, PQgetvalue(res,0,0), strlen(PQgetvalue(res,0,0)));

    return TCL_OK;
}
```

So maybe i'm declaring the variable wrong, i don't know, but what i have found out that's how you shared a variable maybe it's different with a connection, before I was making a new connection for each source file and call that function from TCL like this:

```
PGconn *conn;
PGresult *res;

static int connectDB2(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[]) {

    // check number of arguments
   if (objc != 1) {
            Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 2, objv, "number of argument error");
            return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    conn = PQconnectdb("dbname=jw1_v2 host=localhost user=imdw password=1234");

    if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
       printf("Connection_Error\n");

    }else{
     //printf("Connection_Ok\n");
    }

   return TCL_OK;
 }
```

This is how i Compile the two C files:
samples.c

```
   gcc -shared -o samples.so -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -I/usr/include/tcl samples.c -L/usr/lib -ltcl8.5 -lpq
```

tp_main

```
    gcc -o tp_main -I/usr/include/tcl tp_main.c -L/usr/lib -ltcl8.5 -ltk8.5 -lBLT25 -lpq
```

TCL code would call that function 'connectDB2' and that would be done for each source file, but i don't like that so i'm trying to improve it

Comment: I know this is beside the point of the question, but your code would be more portable if instead of `#include </usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h>`, it said `#include <postgresql/libpq-fe.h>`.  Even better would be `#include "libpq-fe.h"` and then using -I command line options to steer it to the correct directory.

Comment: This seems like a normal variable visibility issue in C, nothing to do with PostgreSQL.  Since your "other source file" is not included from your main source file, how is it getting compiled?  Please show the `make` or `gcc`.

Comment: yes, I think you're right jjanes, how would the compile command be then?? and if i want to include more source files to shared that variable how would the compile command look like, Thanks